# How to get file name in custom layer Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

How to get current batch file name in custom layer?

I tried "filename = generator.filenames" but it return all file name and only for ImageDataGenerator, I'm using custom datagenerator.

```
conv_base = tf.keras.applications.InceptionResNetV2(weights=None,include_top=False , input_shape=(299,299,3))
   
class custom_layer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(custom_layer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        
    def call(self, inputs):
        feature_map = inputs
        file_name = 
        concate_image = 
        return tf.concat([feature_map, concate_image], axis=-1)

new_layer = custom_layer()

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(conv_base)
model.add(tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D())
model.add(new_layer )
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(7,activation='softmax')) 
model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.001), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```